# download video stream without playback on VLC

Tags: command-line, vlc, http-live-streaming

I want to keep streaming video stream from server without playback.
Can I use VLC to do so?

I am using Windows VLC. I tried the following but playback will still pop up.

```
vlc -I dummy --dummy-quiet http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8
```

Thank you

Comment: Probably VLC version problem, works on my vlc 1.1.10 on Win 7

Comment: I tried vlc 1.1.10 on Windows 7 Pro. I face error on acquiring the HLS link above. Can you suggest a link which is working on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

`-I dummy` is the right idea, but you want to direct the output to a file with `--sout`:

```
vlc -I dummy --sout file/ts:output.ts http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/NTV-Public-IPS.m3u8
```